# Ein Märchen zum Kind vs Ein Märchen dem Kind (erzählen)

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context, idiomaticity

Ich habe im Internet gelesen, dass man manchmal den Ausdruck ***ein Märchen zum Kind erzählen*** verwendet anstatt ***ein Märchen dem Kind erzählen***.
Gibt es einen Unterschied in Bezug auf die Beudetung zwischen beiden Ausdrücken oder ist es halt eine Sache vom Stil?
Zum Beispiel:

1. Die Mutter hat zum Kind ein Märchen erzählt.
2. Die Mutter hat dem Kind ein Märchen erzählt.

Comment: Wo im Internet? Ohne Kontext würde ich sagen, »zum Kind erzählen« ist falsch.

Comment: Du kannst "zu jemandem sprechen", aber "zu jemandem erzählen" wäre mir neu.

Comment: könnte es sich dabei um eine automatische Übersetzung aus dem englischen handeln?

Comment: Alternativ möglich wäre allerdings "Die Mutter hat [dem Kind] zum Einschlafen ein Märchen erzählt."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Der Unterschied besteht nur darin, dass "ein Märchen zum Kind erzählen" falsch ist.
Man kann jedoch folgendes sagen: "Märchen sollte man frei und mit Blickkontakt zum Kind erzählen". In diesem Fall ist das "zum" an "Blickkontakt" angekettet und hat nichts mit dem Verb "erzählen" zu tun.

Die Rektion des Verbes "erzählen" (d.h. mit welchen Präpositionen  es verwendet wird) kann man in Wörterbüchern nachlschlagen, z.B. DWDS oder Duden.

Answer (score 2):

"Zum Kind erzählen" geht nicht. Es gibt mit "zu" aber einige andere Redewendungen. Vielleicht waren die gemeint?

> Die Mutter hat [dem Kind] **zum Einschlafen** ein Märchen erzählt.
>
> Die Mutter hat [dem Kind] **zum Nachdenken** ein Märchen erzählt.
>
> Die Lehrerin hat [den Kindern] ein Märchen **zum Thema Freundschaft** erzählt.
>
> Das Buch enthält drei Märchen [für Kinder] **zum Nachspielen**.

Comment: Danke für deine Antwort, Florian.

Comment: Ich habe im Internet etwas wie was Dan oben geschrieben hat. Das Beispiel "Märchen sollte man frei und mit Blickkontakt zum Kind erzählen". Leider kann ich nicht wieder das Beispiel finden. Im Ernst verstehe ich auch nicht warum man im erwähnten von Dan Beispiel das "zum" mit "Blickkontakt" verbinden sollte. "Blickkontakt" arbeitet ja mit "mit".